# Accidentally initialised git repo for my whole desktop

Tags: git

I wanted to create a git repo for one of my apps, however I forgot to CD to the app folder and made a git repo for the whole desktop.

I want to remove this, but I'm afraid if I delete it I will end up deleting all the contents of my desktop, including my app!

how do I backtrack from this?

I'm using a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Just `rm -rf .git` in the same place you ran `git init` to remove the offending git directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git repository keeps track of all its metadata in hidden .git folder. You can safely delete this folder from desktop and re-initialize the repository by going into your's app folder and running git init command.